# Thumbnail could not be created for the image. Please make sure the thumbnail directory is writable.

Tags: file-uploads, thumbnails

I'm getting the following error when trying to upload images on all of the upload directories. The directories are set to 777.

*"Thumbnail could not be created for the image. Please make sure the thumbnail directory is writable."*

If I create a new upload directory I get the same error but it's able to create the _thumbs folder.

Comment: Figured it out. Moved to a new server that was missing the GD2 image library.

Comment: Can you add your fix as an answer below?

Answer (score 4):

Are you 100% sure your Paths are correct in the file upload preferences?

You can check them at... CP Home > File Manager > File Upload Preferences > Edit File Upload Preferences

Also make sure to check who is the "owner" of the folder, it should be the same user that "runs" the php/apache.